# OpenXml: Replace Excel "previewimage" in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating an application in C# (using OpenXML) that based on a PowerPoint template iterates through the slides and replaces all images with SSRS-reports.

This works perfect for images, but one of the elements is an embedded excel sheet which should be editable directly in the presentation (content based on an SSRS report). I am able to render the report and embed it in the PowerPoint presentation, but I cannot work out how to update the "excel preview image" that come along with the embedded excel sheet. This is first updated when entering and exiting the excel sheet in the generated pptx.

The preview image is located at \ppt\media\image.emf (when unzipping the presentation), and I can see the image being updated when entering/exiting as described above. I have converted the excel-sheet to a image so the only bit is to locate and replace this original image.

So how do I access and update this image directly from c#? I have tried several different approaches, but I havent been able to locate the image.. Just knowing which class this image is would be of great help.

Comment: IIRC, you need to call Application.Update on the parent application that created the OLE object before closing the object and quitting the parent application.

Comment: I guess this would be possible if I rendered this through Excel, but I  dont think this is possible when rendering the report through SSRS. On my server I dont even have Office installed, so I need to do this in C#/OpenXml.

Comment: I see.  And probably should have worked that out from your original post.